# Running node process - injecting new Environment Variables

Tags: node.js, process

Lets say I have a node process running. Is there any way to inject new environment variables in the exiting running process.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) or take a look at the `process.env` [in the Node.js documentation.](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env)